# Smooth out boxy faces

Tags: faces, bevel, smooth

how could I make this beveled edge look smoother without having to shade it smooth? Applying an edge split with catmull subsurf works but this in turn ruins everything BUT the edge I am trying to fix (maybe theres a way to apply it just to some faces?).
Help would be much appreciated[image: Boxy look I dont want]

Comment: You need to use Shade Smooth with Auto smooth turned on. Don't use edge split for shading purposes, It's actually very bad for that purpose.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Thank you, exactly what I needed